# WinSCP .NET assembly open stored session

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

How can I use the .NET assembly provided by WinSCP to open a stored session created from the WinSCP application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this. Coupling the assembly with WinSCP application configuration can cause you lots of troubles. The assembly is deliberately isolated from WinSCP application by default.

---

There's nothing that you cannot configure using the [`SessionOptions` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions). Either using its properties, for basic options; or using the [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings), for [advanced settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

Easy way, is to have [WinSCP generate the code for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code).

[image]

---

In the past, you could abuse the `Session.DefaultConfiguration` and the `SessionOptions.HostName` to open a stored session. But the `Session.DefaultConfiguration` has been deprecated since WinSCP 5.8 and will be removed eventually.